# How can I use the FDA package to train data marked as anomalous entries and focus on predicting the number of exits during future anomalous events?

Tags: python, functional-programming, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhBu1.jpg)
In order to study the impact of sudden inflow caused by irregular activities on the number of people exiting at surrounding metro stations, I have pre-filtered the historical time-segmented OD (Origin-Destination) data for the year 2022 to identify anomalous entry volumes and the corresponding exit counts at each station. My goal is to use the FDA (Functional Data Analysis) package in Python to perform time series analysis on these anomalous data and then train a model to predict the number of people exiting during future similar anomalous entry events.

How should I preprocess these data to convert them into time series training data that can be processed by the FDA?

```
import pandas as pd
import skfda
from skfda.preprocessing.dim_reduction.projection import FPCA
# 假設 df 是您已經有的 DataFrame
# 並且 stations 是上述提供的站點列表
df = pd.read_csv('D:/論文資料/CODE/資料處理/2022北捷進出OD/2022_15分鐘/2022活動異常運量分析資料.csv')
df.to_csv('D:/論文資料/CODE/資料處理/2022北捷進出OD/2022_15分鐘/2022活動異常運量分析資料_processed.csv', index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')

# 將 '分秒' 這一列的名稱改為 '分'
df.rename(columns={'分秒': '分'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'人次': '出站人次'}, inplace=True)
df['進站'] = df['進站'].replace('台北101/世貿', '台北101_世貿')
df['日期'] = pd.to_datetime(df['日期'])

df['時段_timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['時段'], unit='h')
df['分_timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['分'], unit='m')


# 現在結合日期、時段、分鐘和秒鐘
df['完整時間戳記'] = df['日期'] + df['時段_timedelta'] + df['分_timedelta'] 
# 移除 '時段' 和 '分' 列
df.drop(['時段_timedelta', '分_timedelta'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# 顯示更新後的 DataFrame
print(df[['日期', '時段', '分',  '完整時間戳記']])



# 確定儲存 CSV 檔案的目錄
output_dir = 'D:/論文資料/CODE/資料處理/2022北捷進出OD/異常運量各站訓練'
stations = [
    "大安森林公園", "三重", "劍潭", "芝山", "台北小巨蛋", "麟光", "動物園",
    "劍南路", "圓山", "北門", "大橋頭站", "雙連", "台北橋", "公館", "紅樹林",
    "淡水", "南港展覽館", "中正紀念堂", "士林", "南勢角", "忠孝敦化", "國父紀念館",
    "市政府", "唭哩岸", "善導寺", "南京三民", "南港軟體園區", "BL板橋", "Y板橋",
    "台北101_世貿", "府中", "台北車站", "西門", "六張犁", "竹圍", "永春",
    "象山", "信義安和", "松山", "南京復興", "忠孝復興", "大安", "忠孝新生"
]

for station in stations:
    # 從 DataFrame 中選擇 '進站' 列匹配當前站點的所有行
    station_data = df[df['進站'] == station]

    # 建立 CSV 檔案的完整路徑
    filepath = f"{output_dir}/{station}.csv"
    
    # 將這些行匯出為 CSV，並指定編碼為 'utf-8-sig'
    station_data.to_csv(filepath, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I have attempted to preprocess the historical data by filtering out the anomalous entries caused by events and calculating the ratio of exits at each station relative to the total number of entries. Additionally, I have pre-labeled the complete timestamps.

The ultimate goal is to use the training data to predict future occurrences of specific sites. Predict the number of outbound people from other sites when there is a sudden inbound traffic.